# Iterating in dataframe and insert on text

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

There is a DataFrame loaded in pandas with size `m*n`, m can be big compare with columnes `n` which are values from 2 to 20.
each value from `m*n` has to be add to expecific text, it means that text between any value is constant.

I tried with `For` and `If` nested sentences, no good result how to make step from df.iloc[0,0] to df.iloc[m,n] and insert in text.

```
textA + df.iloc[0,0] + textB + df.iloc[0,1] + .... + textX + df.iloc[0,n]
textA + df.iloc[1,0] + textB + df.iloc[1,1] + .... + textX + df.iloc[1,n]
.
.
.
textA + df.iloc[m,0] + textB + df.iloc[m,1] + .... + textX + df.iloc[m,n]
```

I have 2 files, one include `textA textB ... textX`  Second file is csv type where pandas dataframe is generated.

With dataframe and text prepare array above.

thanks for any tip.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Could you edit your question and write more clearly what you want the outcome to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly clear on your requirement but takae a look if the following code is able to help you iterate between df.iloc[0,0] to df.iloc[m,n] while adding information from your text file (in this case a text variable)

```
# i am using a dummy variable for the text data as i am not sure how your data look like
text = ['textA', 'textB', 'textC']
new_text = []

# using a nested for loop to iterate
for row in range(len(df)): 
    for col in range(len(df.columns)):
        new_text.append(text[col] + str(df.iloc[row, col]))
```

Comment: the result of `text = ['textA', 'textB', 'textC']` and dataframe row1 `2 4 6` is `textA2 textB4 textC6` and dataframe row2 `8 10 12` result `textA8 textB10 textC12` etc. Text is constant line after line, the variable value is df.iloc[row, col]

Comment: this is an example of how the nested loop work, you can try to adapt it to your code. the text in my example is given as ['textA', 'textB', 'textC'] but in your case it could just be another dataframe or pandas series. from your requirements you state that you wanted `textA + df.iloc[0,0] + textB + df.iloc[0,1] + .... + textX + df.iloc[0,n]` which is similar to 'textA 2 textB 4 textC 6' or am i missing something from the requirement